# Memory Leak with UIScrollView --- Edit: iOS 5.1 Bug

Tags: memory-leaks

Turns out this is an iOS 5.1 Bug. It's well documented if the search is worded correctly :-)

I am using UIScrollView with paging subviews. Somehow these are generating leaks when I test my App in Instruments. I have reduced the code to this simple state and I still leak when thumbing between the 2 subviews. Paging is enabled on the scroll view. I am using ARC.

```
CGRect frame;

    frame.origin.x = self.theScrollPart.frame.size.width * 0;                   
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.theScrollPart.frame.size;

    self->subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.theScrollPart addSubview:subview];

    frame.origin.x = self.theScrollPart.frame.size.width * 1;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.theScrollPart.frame.size;

    self->subview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.theScrollPart addSubview:subview2];

    self.theScrollPart.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.theScrollPart.frame.size.width * 2, self.theScrollPart.frame.size.height);
```

The .h file is:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScrollPart;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *subview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *subview2;
```

Thanks for any help and as always, sorry if I overlooked something obvious.